# Why does this \ifincomplete latex code not work

Tags: pdftex

I have an exam class document, and I want it to output three fields on a page with an incomplete question as follows:

```
page 1 of 2    question 4 continues    please go to next page ...
```

and on the last page I want:

```
page 2 of 2   End of Exam
```

with the code below, I get:

```
page 1 of 2   please go to next page ...
```

and

```
page 2 of 2   End of Exam
```

How do I chage it to print the middle field? I have browsed for help without success, Help will be appreciated.
The code is below

```
\footrule
\lfoot{\footnotesize Page \thepage\ of \numpages}
\cfoot{\newcommand{\continues}{\ifincomplete
{\footnotesize Question \IncompleteQuestion\ continues \hfill Please go to next page\ldots}
{}}}
\rfoot{\iflastpage{End of Exam.}{\footnotesize Please go to next page\ldots}}
```

Comment: Where does `\ifincomplete` in your incomplete (!) example come from?

Comment: It is easier to help you if you add a [minimal working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/) that takes the form `\documentclass{...}\usepackage{....}\begin{document}...\end{document}`. If possible, it should compile and have the minimum amount of code needed to illustrate your problem. This makes it much easier for people to help you - and much more likely that they will!

Comment: I am pretty sure, that `\ifincomplete` ... needs an `\fi` at the end

Comment: I have an example which works (except for the part I have indicated-question continuation). Is it ok to copy and paste latex code without tabbing? because the document is too long, or is there a way to attach?

Comment: I have not been able to post code due to limitation of space, so I have repeated my post (with MWE) here "http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30963912/part-of-latex-exam-class-document-does-not-work"